# Example about monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble with finding examples for the follwing;

1) A function f:(-1,1) to R (real numbers) which is continuous and monotonic increasing, but not differentiable at 0.
I have been thinking about taking - abs(x) but I did not see that this function would guarantee it is monotonic increasing, so it did not work.

2)A function f:R TO R which is strictly monotonic increasing and differentiable on R, with the property that it is derivative at 0 is zero.
Here I used f(x)=x^3, I think it works with this one.

I really need any[ hint for part 1.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=3x$ are both continuous and monotonic increasing

Comment: You tried $$f(x)=\lvert x\rvert=\begin{cases}ax&\text{if }x\ge 0\\ bx&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$ with $a=1,\ b=-1$ and it didn't work. Try with another $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1/ you can use a simple piece wise function:

$$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{3} x &\text{ if }& x<0 \\ 2x  &\text{ otherwise}\end{array} \right.
$$

Your 2/ is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your example in 2) is fine.

1): let $f(x)=0 $ if $x \in(-1,0)$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x \in [0,1)$